# Delete a node from a linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list

```
class StackNode{
    int data;
    StackNode next;

    public StackNode(int data, StackNode next){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

public class StackWithLinkedList {

    StackNode root = null;

    public void push(int data){
        if(root == null)
            root = new StackNode(data, null);
        else {
            StackNode temp = root;
            while(temp.next != null)
                temp = temp.next;

            temp.next = new StackNode(data, null);
        }
    }

    public int pop() throws Exception{
        if(root == null)
            throw new Exception("No Elements in Stack");
        else {
            StackNode temp = root;
            while(temp.next != null)
                temp = temp.next;
            int data = temp.data;
            temp = null;
            return data;
        }
    }


    public void print(){
        StackNode temp = root;
        while(temp!= null){
            System.out.print(temp.data +" ");
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackWithLinkedList stack = new StackWithLinkedList();
        for(int i = 1; i<=15; i++){
            Random randomGen = new Random();
            stack.push(randomGen.nextInt(i));
        }
        stack.print();
        System.out.print("\n");
        try {
            System.out.println("Deleted: "+stack.pop());
            System.out.println("Deleted: "+stack.pop());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stack.print();
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement Stack with Linkedlist. In pop function i am traversing till the last node and making it null. When i print the list. it remain unchanged. Does assigning root to temp and traversing with it cause any problem?

Comment: You should set field next to null of element before the last one. Not the element

Comment: But i made that element itself as null. Wont that free the memory?

Comment: You should not be interested in free memory since GC will take care of that. You sould remove reference to that element from list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid this all together by simplifying your implementation. It's just a stack so it's LIFO. All you need to do is make the last element `push`-ed the `root`. When `pop`-ing return the `data` in `root` and set `root` to the next in line.

The way you're doing it increases the typical complexity of `O(1)` to `O(N)` for the `push` and `pop` operations.

Something like:

```
public void push(int data) {
    root = new StackNode(data, root);
}

public int pop() throws Exception {
    if (root == null)
        throw new Exception("No Elements in Stack");
    else {
        int data = root.data;
        root = root.next;
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answer by @ChiefTwoPencils, that must be the preferred way of implementing this. However, to correct your logic of pop operation you shall keep track of second last item and once you get that you can return data value of next node and set the next link to null.

Here is changed logic from your code of pop method

```
     public int pop() throws Exception{
        if(root == null)
            throw new Exception("No Elements in Stack");
        else {
            int data = -1;
            if(root.next==null) {
                data = root.data;
                root = null;
                return data;
            }

            StackNode temp = root;
            while(temp.next.next != null)
                temp = temp.next;
            data = temp.next.data;
            temp.next = null;
            return data;
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int pop() throws Exception{
   if(root == null)
       throw new Exception("No Elements in Stack");
   else {
       StackNode temp = root;
       StackNode prev;
       while(temp.next != null){
           prev = temp;
           temp = temp.next;
       }
       int data = temp.data;
       prev.next = null;
       return data;
   }
```

}